# CQ5 - footer with same parsys components for all pages withing a website

Tags: html, footer, aem

I have footer with 3 parsys divs. If I add some component to that parsys(for example the Text component) I can't see it in another pages. Is it possible to have 1 common footer with 3 parsys components for all pages within a website?

I have this code in my `myApp/components/page/footer.jsp`

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.commons.Doctype, com.day.cq.i18n.I18n, com.day.text.Text" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<div id="footer">
<hr />
<div id="left-footer-cell" class="footer-cell">
<cq:include path="fc1" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
</div>
<div id="mid-footer-cell" class="footer-cell">
<cq:include path="fc2" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
</div>
<div id="right-footer-cell" class="footer-cell">
<cq:include path="fc3" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `iparsys`. From the **[Adobe docs](http://wem.help.adobe.com/enterprise/en_US/10-0/wem/wcm/default_components.html#Inheritance%20Paragraph%20System%20%28iparsys%29)**:

> The inherited paragraph system is a paragraph system that also allows
>   you to inherit the created paragraphs from the parent. You add
>   paragraphs to iparsys at for example, `/content/geometrixx/en/products`
>   and as result, all the subpages of products that also have `iparsys`
>   with the same name inherit the created paragraphs from the parent. On
>   each level, you can add more paragraphs, which are then inherited by
>   the children pages. You can also cancel paragraph inheritance at a
>   level at any time.

You can use an **iparsys** in your page just like a regular paragraph system that you have above, simply by chaning the `resourceType` to `iparsys`:

```
<div id="left-footer-cell" class="footer-cell">
    <cq:include path="fc1" resourceType="foundation/components/iparsys" />
</div>
<div id="mid-footer-cell" class="footer-cell">
    <cq:include path="fc2" resourceType="foundation/components/iparsys" />
</div>
<div id="right-footer-cell" class="footer-cell">
    <cq:include path="fc3" resourceType="foundation/components/iparsys" />
</div>
```

The content you drag in will then get inherited by the child pages. (They'll also need to use a template that references `fc1`, `fc2` and `fc3` to pull in the content.)